# Customize NSIS installer with Electron-builder

Tags: electron, nsis, electron-builder

I want to customize NSIS script - e.g. remove **Finish Page** and run app immediately after install (assisted installer is used).

I use modifying scrpt: `include: build/installer.nsh`.

It opens *myApp* after install but **Finish** page is still there.

```
!include MUI2.nsh

!macro customInstall
  ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\myapp.exe" /sw'
!macroend
```

I mean I don't want to show the last page **Completing myApp Setup** as shown in gif.

[image: install process]

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Hi Boris, could you send a screenshot of the finish page you're talking about? Or even better a gif of the whole installation process with the finish page.

Comment: Hi @Joshua. I added gif to the post, please look at it.

Comment: Thank you Boris, that's really helpful. Unfortunately I don't know how I can solve your problem sorry.

Comment: You can also use oneclick option if you would like the streamlined experience

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I did it in *build/installer.nsh*:

```
!macro RunApp
  ${StdUtils.ExecShellAsUser} $0 "$launchLink" "open" ""
!macroend

!macro customInstall
    !insertmacro RunApp
    !insertmacro quitSuccess
!macroend
```